# Linear separability / Number of positive solutions of a random linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, inequality

This one is on linear separability of cyclic patterns.

**The shorter geometric version:**

Take a ring of length $p$ of  randomly assigned mean-free binary values $x_i = \pm 1$, $i = 1 \cdots p$. Cyclically, form $p$ vectors $V_i$ of length $n$ with components $V_{i,j} = x_i \, x_{((j+i)\bmod p)}$, $j = 1 \cdots n$.

For large $p$, what is the smallest $n^* = n^*(p)$ such that all of these $p$ vectors $V_i$ lie in a halfspace? This is to be understood with probabilty at least one half, when averaged over all rings.

**The longer algebraic version:**

Consider $p$ many binary values $x_i = \pm 1$, $i = 1 \cdots p$. Consider all choices of the sets {$x_i$}  with the "mean-free" condition $\sum_{i=1}^p x_i = 0$, i.e. there  are $p \choose p/2$ many ways to choose the sets of  {$x_i$}.

Let $\Theta(q)$ be the indicator function which is $\Theta(q) = 1$ if $q > 0$,  $\Theta(q) = 0$ if $q \leq 0$.
Let $n < p$. Consider $n$ many real values $w_j$, $j = 1 \cdots n$. For a given  choice of  {$x_i$}, one would like to find values {$w_j$}, such that $f = 1$ in
$$
f (\left\{ x_i  \right\} ) =  \max_{\{ w_j \}} \prod_{i=1}^p \Theta {\Large\{ }\sum_{j=1}^n w_j \; x_i \, x_{((j+i)\bmod p)} {\Large\} }
$$
In other words, all of the $p$ many linear expressions (for $i = 1 \cdots p$)
$$
\tag{1} \sum_{j=1}^n w_j \; x_i \, x_{((j+i)\bmod p)}
$$
for that choice of  {$x_i$} shall be positive, then $f =1$.

Now we ask about the capacity, i.e. the smallest number $n^*$ for which 
$$
g(p,n) = \frac{1}{p \choose p/2}
\sum_{ \left\{ x_i  \right\} }  f (\left\{ x_i  \right\} ) \geq \frac12
$$

The counting function $g(p,n)$ counts the fraction of all sets of  {$x_i$} for which the above linear expressions **[1]** can be made positive, and we want that to be the case for at least half of all the choices of the sets of  {$x_i$}.

For large $p$, what is $n^* = n^*(p)$?

**Remarks:**

1. The relation $n^* = n^*(p)$ will be linear.
2. It is clear that $n^* < p$ since if $n^*=p$,  the above linear expressions **[1]** would be $p$ expressions in $p$ unknowns {$w_j$}, which could be  solved for {$w_j$} simply by equating all expressions to $1$, say.
3. Large-scale numerical evidence indicates $n^* = p / (1.70 \pm 0.02)$ (Martin Schroeder).
4. If the random variables in the linear expressions **[1]** would not have the "ring" structure (note the "mod" in the index), but instead if one would select  $n \times p$ many mean-free variables  $x_{j, i}$ and demand that the $p$ many expressions $\sum_{j=1}^n w_j \; x_{j, i}$ be positive, then $n^* = p / 2$ (Thomas Cover) (the famous function counting theorem).